# Why doesn't "find -print0" work in Cygwin under Vista?

Tags: filesystems, cygwin, shell-script, pipe, gnu

I'm writing a simple shell script:

```
find datafiles/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum > datafiles.md5
```

In Cygwin under Vista, it just sits there and nothing happens. 
It works fine on Linux.

What could be the problem??

fyi:

```
$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.0
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
Built using GNU gnulib version e5573b1bad88bfabcda181b9e0125fb0c52b7d3b
Features enabled: O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION FTS() CBO(level=0)
```

Comment: I found a related posting here, with no solution:
http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2009-07/msg00245.html

Comment: For what it's worth, it works fine under cygwin/XP.

Comment: I use it under Cygwin/Vista all the time and it works fine for me.

Comment: I just found out it works fine with local filesystems. It only doesn't work over the network!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the command apart. What does

```
find datafiles/ -type f -print0
```

give you? What does

```
find datafiles/ -type f
```

give you? What does

```
find datafiles/
```

give you? What does

```
ls -ld datafiles/
```

give you?

Comment: The 'find' command seems to think everything is a folder (-type f doesn't work). The problem only affects files on a particular network mount that I was trying to work with. I finally gave up and took a different approach.